# set datepicker mindate with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am trying to set a minDate in a jquery-ui datepicker. The date is retrieved using jquery from a data attribure of a parent node.

```
<p data-min-date="2015-03-10">Date:
    <input id="datepicker" type="text">
</p>
<script>
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        minDate: $(this).closest('p').data('minDate'),
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    });
</script>
```

You can check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D4AGz/401/) to see that the minDate is not considered by the datepicker.

Can you spot what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because `$(this)` in the scope of the `datepicker` intialiser does not equal the element which was selected. To do what you require, you need to wrap the `datepicker()` call in an `each()` and iterate over every element of the selector:

```
$("#datepicker").each(function() {
    $(this).datepicker({
        minDate: $(this).closest('p').data('minDate'),
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    });
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/D4AGz/402/)

Alternatively, if the datpicker will only ever be created on a single element, you can select it directly for the `minDate` property:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    minDate: $("#datepicker").closest('p').data('minDate'),
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/D4AGz/403/)

Comment: how we can add mindate as current date? so that will automatically update.

Comment: @GaneshAher `minDate: new Date()`

Comment: minDate: new Date() is not working. $('#datepicker5').datepicker({
      autoclose: true,
      //changeYear: true,
      minDate: new Date(),
    });

Comment: Yes it does: http://jsfiddle.net/D4AGz/1287/. Check your console for errors. If you still cannot get it to work I'd suggest you read the jQueryUI documentation, or start a question about it.

Comment: Please go through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47768636/mindate-0-not-working-in-datepicker this question. Thanks

Comment: You're using the Bootstrap datepicker. This question is about the jQueryUI one