# minDate: 0, not working in datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, mindate

I'm using a AdminLte template for my CodeIgniter application, and from that I'm using a Datepicker plugin. I'm trying to add `minDate` functionality to restrict user to access previous date from current date, but the `minDate: 0` is not working and I'm able to pick previous date also.

**Here is my JS:**

```
$('#datepicker5').datepicker({
      autoclose: true,
      //changeYear: true,
      minDate: 0,
    });
```

and

```
$('#datepicker5').datepicker({
      autoclose: true,
      //changeYear: true,
      minDate: new Date(),
    })
```

Today's date is *12 Dec. 2017* but I can select previous date also.
[image]
Both are not working.

I'm using two date pickers with two different ID's. One is `datepicker4` and `datepicker5`, and I'm calculating diff. between them. For that I've written following JS:

```
$('#datepicker4').datepicker();
  $('#datepicker5').datepicker();
  $('#datepicker5').change(function () {
      var gasDiff= $('#datepicker4').datepicker("getDate") - $('#datepicker5').datepicker("getDate");
      var result = gasDiff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) * -1;

      document.getElementById("gasDiff").value = result;
  });
```

Even I can able to select expiry date before issue date.
Actually I want to pick issue date before or current date, and expiry date after current date.

**Edit:**

```
$('#datepicker1').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    endDate: new Date(),
    todayHighlight: true,

  });

  $("#datepicker1").on("change",function(){
        var selected = "Are you sure you want to select this date ?";
        alert(selected);
    });
  //$('#datepicker1')..inputmask('dd/mm/yyyy', { 'placeholder': 'dd/mm/yyyy' });

  $('#datepicker2').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    startDate: new Date(),
  });

  $('#datepicker1', '#datepicker2').change(function(){
    var certDiff= $('#datepicker1').datepicker("getDate") - $('#datepicker2').datepicker("getDate");    
    var result = certDiff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) * -1;
    //("#certDiff").text(result);
    document.getElementById("certDiff").value = result;
    //document.getElementById("certDiff").innerHTML = result;
  });
```

Please any kind of help is welcome, Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not a codeigniter related problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described `bootstrap-datepicker` plugin is working with `startDate: new Date()` attribute

```js
$('#datepicker4').datepicker({
autoclose: true,
startDate: new Date() 
});

$('#datepicker5').datepicker({
 autoclose: true,
 startDate: new Date(),
}).change(function(){
var gasDiff= $('#datepicker4').datepicker("getDate") - $(this).datepicker("getDate");    
var result = gasDiff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) * -1;
  $("#gasDiff").text(result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input type="text" id="datepicker4"/>
<input type="text" id="datepicker5"/>
<div id="gasDiff">

</div>
```

Comment: How we can make on change event for both the datepickers ? Now it work on second datepicker only, means it gives difference only if I change the value of second datepicke, but if I made change date from first datepicker the duration is not changed.

Comment: If I select date from second datepicker first it gives wrong result

Comment: I tried and made all changes for change event, but it did not give any result for duration.  Please check my updated question.

Comment: Please check the [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/753o8kkc/2/#&togetherjs=UcP5vrDz0s). May it helps!

Answer (score 3):

This looks like the `bootstrap-datepicker` plugin. Use `startDate: "12/12/2017"` instead of `minDate: new Date()`.

You can find more details in the [documentation](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#startdate)

Comment: @GaneshAher I've edited my answer. The `startDate` property value must be a string that has the same format as the format you've set. The default one is `mm/dd/yyyy`